# replace HTML image source with SSI tag

Tags: html, http, ssi, lwip

i'm trying to change the image displayed on my website with an SSI tag. 
What i'm trying to do is this

```
<img src="<!--#tag2-->" alt="randompicture">
```

My webserver is running on a STI M7 microcontroller, i know my ssi is working with this website. With ssi i just send the file location: ./files/logo.png
Does anybody can help me to get this working? 
I know there are a lot of different options to do this, but i can only use SSI/CGI since these are the only protocols i have implemented in my micrcontroller. I'm not a webdesigner and only have basic HTML/CSS skills but i'm open for every solution! 
Thank you all.

SOLVED:

Well i solved my own problem. Instead of replacing the file name in the image source with an SSI tag. I just replaced the complete html code line for including an image and replaced this with my SSI tag....

Comment: If you solved your question please either post an answer and accept it or delete the question